# Value on Object is null when sending from axios to API Controller.How to solve it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, axios

I am making React Crud Application and when try to send data from axios to API Controller I am not able to send those data, while checking in API I found that all the the values are null. But with the same API and values i tried from POSTMAN it worked perfectly. How Can i solve this?

```
import React, { FormEvent, useState } from 'react'
import { Segment, Grid, GridColumn, Button, Form, Container } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { IEmployee } from '../Model/activity'
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios';
import {v4 as uuid} from 'uuid';

interface DetailParams {
    id: string;
}

const EmployeeForm : React.FC<RouteComponentProps<DetailParams>> = ({ match, history }) => {

    const [employee, setEmployee] = useState<IEmployee>({
        id: '',
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        address: '',
        organization: ''
    })

    const handleInputChange = (event: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {

        const { name, value } = event.currentTarget;
        setEmployee({ ...employee, [name]: value })
    }


    const handleSubmit = () => {

        console.log(employee);

        if (employee.id.length === 0) {
            let newActivity = {
                ...employee,
                id: uuid(),
            }
            console.log(employee);
            axios.post('https://localhost:44353/Employee/CreateEmployee',{data : employee})
            .then((response) => {
                history.push(`/manage/${newActivity.id}`)
            })

        } else {
            axios.post('https://localhost:44353/Employee/EditEmployee',{data : employee})
            .then((response) => {
                history.push(`/manage/${employee.id}`)
            })
        }
    }

    return (
        <Container style={{ marginTop: '7em' }}>
        <Grid>
            <GridColumn width={10}>
                <Segment clearing>
                    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <Form.Input name='firstName' onChange={handleInputChange} placeholder='First Name' value={employee.firstName} />
                        <Form.TextArea name='lastName' onChange={handleInputChange} placeholder='Last Name' value={employee.lastName} />
                        <Form.Input name='address' onChange={handleInputChange} placeholder='Address' value={employee.address} />
                        <Form.Input name='organization' onChange={handleInputChange}  placeholder='Organization' value={employee.organization} />
                       

                        <Button floated='right' positive type='submit' content='Submit' />
                        <Button onClick={() => history.push('/employeeList')} floated='right' type='button' content='Cancel' />

                    </Form>
                </Segment>
            </GridColumn>
        </Grid>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default EmployeeForm
```

The above is my form class from where the data is to be send from axios.
While Console.log in handle submit button the values are displayed perfectly.

My NET.Core API is :-

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> CreateEmployee([FromBody] Employee Employee)
        {
            var result = await _employeeService.CreateEmployee(Employee);
            return Ok(Employee.FirstName);
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `{data : employee}` be `{data : newActivity }` ?

Comment: What does `console.log(employee);` print inside `handleSubmit`?

Comment: @ABGR console.log(employee) inside handleSubmit prints something like this:

Object
 address: "asda"
 firstName: "Kritarth"
 id: ""
 lastName: "Acahr"
 organization: "asdas"
__proto__: Object

baiscally it print object and inside object there is the value of the form

Comment: I also tried {data: newActivity} instead of {data: employee} but that didn't help

Answer (score 0):

It was wrong with syntax. when chane changed `axios.post('https://localhost:44353/Employee/CreateEmployee',{data : employee})` to `axios.post('https://localhost:44353/Employee/CreateEmployee',employee)` it worked fine